# hide element after line-break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive footer, but this is maybe interesting for other responsive elements, too.

Is there a possibility to hide an element, if the line breaks at its position?

```
<footer>
John Doe · Main Street 123 · Sometown · +12 3456 789
</footer>
```

I want for wide screens:

```
John Doe · Main Street 123 · Sometown · 012 3456 789
```

And for smaller screens then for example:

```
John Doe · Main Street 123 · Sometown
012 3456 789
```

or

```
John Doe · Main Street 123
Sometown · 012 3456 789
```

etc.

So the dividing dot disappears if there is a line break, because it's no more needed and does not look nice at the end or beginning of a line.

Edit: Some possible markup

```
<footer>
John&nbsp;Doe<span class="hide-when-linebreak"> · </span>Main&nbsp;Street&nbsp;123<span class="hide-when-linebreak"> · </span>Sometown<span class="hide-when-linebreak"> · </span>+12&nbsp;3456&nbsp;789
</footer>
```

Haven't found any solution for this, maybe there is an idea how to start?

Thx

Comment: First of all, you don’t _have_ any individual elements to hide here, because it is just one line of text. You should create a proper HTML structure first, and then insert those bullets via CSS. // There is no way in CSS to select elements based on that they are (currently) the first element “on a line.” Might be possible to somehow fake the effect using negative margins and hidden overflow.

Comment: But first of all, I would challenge your _“is not needed any more”_ and _“does not look nice”_ argument. If those bullets are needed to separate content parts with different meanings from one another optically, then I would argue that you should leave them in place, even at the end of a line. Otherwise you are relying purely on the line break to convey separation of text parts with different meanings, and that‘s a little “thin.” I would just see to it that the bullet always stays on the end of the line in these cases, and doesn’t break to the beginning of the next one.

Comment: i think its a great question as there is possibility that we can face this situation i will search for the answer no matter from css or javascript but this situation is a 100% valid situation +1

Comment: @CBroe 1. Yes, thank you. Edited some possible markup. 2. In my opinion a divider is needed to separate the parts, if they are next to each other in a horizontal line, But if a line break is dividing the part vertically, the dividing character is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this JavaScript function to dynamically set the footer contents on page load and every resize of the window:

```js
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
    var footer = 'John Doe · Main Street 123 · Sometown · +12 3456 789' +
                 ' · jd@example.com · www.example.com';
    footer = footer.trim().replace(/&/g, '&amp;') // encode HTML entities
                          .replace(/</, '&lt;')
                          .replace(/([^·])\s+/g, '$1&nbsp;'); // don't allow breaks here
    var $footer = $('footer');
    var html = ''; // actual content to be put in footer
    var height = 0; // actual height of the footer
    footer.split(/· /).forEach(function (part, i) {
        $footer.html(html + (i ? '· ': '') + part); // try, and see what we get
        // Depending on height increase, place a break or a non-breaking space
        $footer.html(html += (i ? ($footer.height() > height ? '<br>' : '·&nbsp;') : '')
                          + part);
        height = $footer.height();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that based on the line break per say, but you can achieve pretty much the same effect using a simple media query.

Edit: looks like StackOverflow doesn't work with breakpoints… here's a pen: http://codepen.io/memoblue/pen/oLVEOX

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  div {
    display: block;
  }
  .sm-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>John Doe · Main Street 123 <span class="sm-hidden">·</span></div><div> Sometown · +12 3456 789</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, tried that, too. yes. But sadly this only works if you know the length of the words and the font size.

Comment: Understood. But in this case, design wise, I think it usually looks better if you give your content a more "rigid" formatting at a few breakpoints instead of letting the content dictate the layout. I'd recommend you give it a shot and see how it looks :) The trick is to find the right combo of breakpoints…